# Using Data.Typeable's cast with a locally defined data type

Tags: haskell, types, casting

I have a data type which I'm using to represent a [wxAny](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_any.html) object in wxHaskell, currently I only support `wxAny`s which contain a `String` or an `Int`, thus:

```
data Any
  = IsString String
  | IsInt Int
  | IsUndefined
```

I need a function (`a -> Any`) and I'm wondering if I can do it elegantly using `Data.Typeable`, or if anyone can suggest another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it relatively simply by combining the `cast` function with pattern guards:

```
f :: Typeable a => a -> Any
f x
    | Just s <- cast x = IsString s
    | Just n <- cast x = IsInt n
    | otherwise = IsUndefined
```

That does require that the input be an instance of `Typeable`, but most standard types have a `deriving Typeable` clause so it's usually not a problem.

Comment: How does it know that Just s and Just n are different?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a type-class for this:

```
class ToAny a where
  toAny :: a -> Any

instance ToAny Int where
  toAny = IsInt

instance ToAny String where
  toAny = IsString
```

For the other case, you could just not call the function on values of other types - it would be less code.